# Xcode horizontal ScrollView

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I am trying to make a horizontal `ScrollView`. I was able to set the size the scrollView.

However, I was trying to make views, but I tried to do it with Storyboard (which I think is really dumb, since I can't really see the box beyond). I am trying to make 5 views that each has 2 label and 1 `UIImageView` with specific size, but how do I generate views programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content).

It's a bit of a vague question to answer directly. I suggest reading that tutorial and then coming back with any concrete questions you have.

Comment: I am trying to create a scrollView dynamically from my database. I want to choose the top 5 objects with most clicks and synthesize UIImageView and UILabel for it. How should I do it?